# QCubed/QCodo LoadAll Not Defined

Tags: php, qcodo, qcubed

I'm using Qcubed framework for my application and i'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Users::LoadAll() in C:\xampp\htdocs\andret\admin\users.php on line 183
```

What is the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information or code examples I can only guess but you could try these things and see if they help. 
Check that users.php loads the QCubed framework,
Check that you have run codegen and that Users.class.php exists in your includes/models directory.
Is admin/users.php a class file? If so did you name the class Users? If that is the case you may want to rename that class as AdminUsers so that it doesn't conflict with the Users class in your models as of yet QCubed does not use PHP's name-spacing.

Comment: Was a name conflict the class i was working was users and the table users i changed the class to UsersClass so i worked fine

Comment: Did you change the model to UsersClass? if so you may have an issue the next time you run the codegen as it will create a new Users class in the models directory if it does not find one.